# Animation errors in Bootstrap Carousel Implementation - slides do not 'push' each other on/off

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

http://gabemcclelland.com/private/appybday/

As you can see, when the slideshow goes to the next slide/image, it seems to load halfway across the screen instead of 'pushing' the other slide off.

I've tried:

Removing special classes used to style the inner wrapper 'screen' of the phone

Removing 'pause:hover" function on the initial carousel function call

Comment: This is your code? $('.carousel').carousel({
 interval: 4000
})

Comment: Yes. There are also external files (jquery, carousel.js, transition.js ) that are referenced at the bottom of the html

Comment: You have the old version of the bootstrap.css and carousel script running at your page, update it to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Added - No change in behavior though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Remove all the `width` and `height` attributes from your `img` tags and add it as CSS instead:

```
<img src="http://gabemcclelland.com/private/appybday/img/slide03.png" alt="slide03" />
```

Add the following line in your CSS:

```
.iphone img {
    height: 480px;
    width: 321px;
}
```

Also make sure to update your transition.js script (and all other boostrap scripts that you might have), you're loading the outdated version.